# How do I set chosen environment variable to the Attachmate.Emulation.Frame.exe

Tags: c#, controls, terminal-emulator, unified-service-desk, attachmate-extra

Back Story:

I am the technical lead for a large CRM shop.  One of the application in which utilizes Unified Service Desk.  There was a requirement in maintenance to fix an application in which Unified Services Desk uses a hosted control which houses a child control which houses a terminal emulator (Attachmate newest version).

I had a sub contractor working on this and was a few weeks behinds already.  We eventually lost him and someone needed to fix this. I won't pretend to be a USD expert (although I've learned about hosted controls within the past few days) but it was either I who had some bandwidth and knows c# or someone else who knew USD well but had zero bandwidth; the latter was decided to handle this which is me.

I've fully read through the code and actually have the terminal emulator showing in the child control.

Another requirement is to automatically login to the legacy system in which the terminal emulator is a reflection of.

I am having the darndest time trying to set chosen environment variables (username, password) and set to the Attachmate.Emulation.Frame.exe so that the user will automatically login to legacy.

I have the following in my `session` class within `beginReflection()` method:

```
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("UserName", username);
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PassWord", password);
startInfo.FileName = @"C:...\...\Reflection\Attachmate.Emulation.Frame.exe";
```

Am I not approaching this correctly?  Does anybody out there have any insight?  This is horribly time sensitive and was just dropped on my lap with the client already mad bc is already late.

Regards.

Comment: Passwords in environmental variables?  Ewww

Comment: I didn't design it.  This code will eventually be merged with another application in which will be redesigned.  I just need this fixed.